# Can this triple SysEq have multiple solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

A) $x+2y-z=6$
B) $2x-y+3z=-13$
C) $3z-2y+3z=-16$

I got $x=-1$ , $y=2$ , $z=-3$

But, then I also got $x=11$ , $y=27$ , $z=-32$
by combining and eliminating in a different order.

Is this possible?

Comment: Substitute the values back into the original equations (do they work ?). Check these value in intermediate steps ... check your working that attained these intermediate equations.

Comment: It is a good idea to check your answer in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$11+2(27)-(-32)=11+54+32> 6$$

The second proposed solution is not a solution to the linear system.

While for a general linear systems of equations might have more than one solution, in this case, note that the determinant of the corresponding matrix is non-zero, the solution should be unique.

```
>> det([1 2 -1; 2 -1 3; 3 -2 3])

ans =

    10
```